# How can I move all nodes in specific direction in single animation using cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, position, cytoscape.js

I want to do something like this:

```
cy.nodes().animate({
    position: { x: x + 100, y: y + 100 },
});
```

but that doesn't work. I simply don't know how to access node's current position. I think I am just missing something simple here.

Comment: Do you need the animation? Otherwise you can use [`cy.nodes().shift()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.shift). That way, you just need to specify the offset and not the current position (which you can do for a single node with [`cy.$('#id').position()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position))

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be a single animation - whole group of nodes moving at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by using `preset` layout:

```
cy.nodes().layout({
  name: 'preset',
  animate: true,
  fit: false,
  transform: (node) => {
    let position = {};
    position.x = node.position('x') + 100;
    position.y = node.position('y') + 100;
    return position;
  }
}).run();
```

For more options see the [doc](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/preset).

Here is a [JS Bin](https://output.jsbin.com/keteducofa/1) demo (press animate button).

Comment: This worked for me when i changed `position.x` to `node._private.position.x`, for position.x i had undefined, position itself was set to either false or true?

Comment: This is interesting: if the position of the node is not changed, then the `position` argument of transform function is `false`. But you still don't have to access `_private`. `node.position()` should work as usual.

Comment: agreed, the node variable is as it should be, this is a bug probably. I had another problem with your code, the edges are still at the same place when calling the layout on the nodes and not all elements. Maybe `cy.elements()` and `node.position().x/y`?

Comment: You guys made me create a demo, I edited my answer and added a demo. Apparently, you need to make a deep copy of the position object.